# Validate an XML file as a build event

Tags: asp.net, xml, validation, pre-build-event

I was wondering if there was a way to validate XML files as part of a pre-build event, so that I can go back and fix the problem before the app starts up.

I'm aware of (and use) code to validate XML files on **application startup** as part of serialization ([XmlReaderSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.aspx) with [ValidationEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationeventhandler.aspx)), but I'd like some way of validating the XML before the app starts running.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a script task provided in [msbuildtasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) in your build file may be sufficient for validating.

Comment: Thanks! I guess it's time to put msbuildtasks back in.